# Google Cloud Sdk from DataProc Cluster

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-pubsub

What is the right way to use/install python google cloud apis such as pub-sub from a google-dataproc cluster? For example if im using zeppelin/pyspark on the cluster and i want to use the pub-sub api, how should i prepare it?

It is unclear to me what is installed and what is not installed during default cluster provisioning and if/how I should try to install python libraries for google cloud apis.

I realise additionally there may be scopes/authentication to setup.
To be clear, I can use the apis locally but I am not sure what is the cleanest way to make the apis accessible from the cluster and I dont want to perform any unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, at the moment, you need to bring your own client libraries for the various Google APIs unless using the [Google Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector) or [BigQuery connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector) from Java or via RDD methods in PySpark which automatically delegate into the Java implementations.

For authentication, you should simply use `--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub` and/or `--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` and the service account on the Dataproc cluster's VMs will be able to authenticate to use PubSub via the default installed credentials flow.